# How do I Get control's content by name inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to access label by name inside DataTemplate in code behind file. But I am unable to access it by 'Editlbl' name. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<DataGrid Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle}" Background="White" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding ShowDataGrid}" Name="ProductsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Id" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label x:Name="Editlbl">Edit</Label>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: If you search for this on StackOverflow, you see that it's usually commented with "why do you want to do this at all". So what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Clemens I want to bind it with an event in parent file in which this usercontrol is used

Comment: @Clemens All of my events are in parent file so I want this to be in it as well

Comment: You want to use it like a Button? Than you should use a Button (and perphaps style it like a Label), and bind its Command property to a view model command.